# SocialEngine - Link to a classifieds category

Tags: javascript, jquery, socialengine

I'm looking for a way to provide a link directly to a social classifieds category. It's looking like it will be a pretty generic solution to make a dropdown populate via URL, or something :p

If you look here - http://demo.socialengine.net/classifieds

On the right, you'll see a filter box, the first of the option is a category. As soon as you select a category the page reloads (but the url doesn't change) presenting the selected category.

I need to make 2 links to particular categories, so I'm hoping someone can provide an interesting way to make it work. Hopefully that demo site can give enough info.

Thanks Stackers!

Answer (score 0):

I found some way, try bellow:

http://demo.socialengine.net/classifieds?category=6

Pass the category parameter in URL, but this is an id, not much SEO friendly.

I'll update here, if there is another good solution.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will make a drop down with links for each option within dropdown:

```
<select class="styled" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0; font-size: 13px; height: 49px;"onchange="if (this.value) window.location.href=this.value">

<option>OTHER</option>
<?php   foreach ($this->categories as $key=>$cat){  ?>
<option value= "/classifieds?category=<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $cat; ?></option>
<?php  } ?>     
</select>
```

You need link for only two options you give condition within the foreach loop like `if($key<2)` then this will make link for two options and for rest it will simply form a dropdown.